# How to execute a simple php script in WP (I don't think wp_enque_script applies here)

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-script

I have a wordpress page where I want to include a [budget calculation tool](http://www.thecreditguy.tv/free-budget-tool/).

This budget calculation tool is of course tied to a php script that executes the fields in the budget calculation tool. This php script lives in the file "view.php"

My question is: how can I execute this php script in Wordpress

Here is the [script](http://girlscancode.com/budget/index.html) working in a simple HTML/CSS/Js form:

I am so sure this is a beginner thing, but I just can't get my head around it! What am I missing here?

Thanks so much!

Best,

Gabriela

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to add it to whatever page template you would like. The `view.php` file sounds like the wrong place, but if you want it there, just add that code to whatever section of the page you want.

If you want to go a better route, I'd turn that bad boy into a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Shortcodes have a bit of a learning curve, but are extremely useful. The benefit to this being that instead of having to copy/paste the code into a new area each time - you can just call [calculator] or whatever you eventually name the shortcode. If you want to execute the shortcode in a template file simply put something like this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[calculator]'); ?>`

Answer (score 3):

I would go about this by creating a custom [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates). Then plug in the HTML and apply the scripts to this template by embedding the scripts or using wp-enqueue. Then you need to create a new page in WP and assign it the page template you just created with the calculation tool.